# Turn off inline hook for child documents knitr

Tags: r, latex, hook, knitr

I have a document with the following parent/child structure

> Master
>
> > Chapter1
> >
> > > Analysis 1
> > >
> > > > Results 1
> >
> > Chapter 2
> >
> > > Analysis 2
> > >
> > > > Results 2

In my Chapter 1 child, I set:

```
inline_hook <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    # ifelse does a vectorized comparison
    # If integer, print without decimal; otherwise print two places
    res <- ifelse(x == round(x),
      sprintf("%d", x),
      sprintf("%.2f", x)
    )
    paste(res, collapse = ", ")
  }
}

knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)
```

However, this rolls over into my chapter 2 child documents (breaking some tables), how do I prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried setting inline to NULL in the next chunk?